# Can't render and test my component with enzyme and jest when React.Memo is present

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

My component is wrapped around with `Memo`:

```
const FamilyVariantTags = React.memo((
  { project, combineVariants, cloneToIllumina, variant, variantTagNotes, family, projectTagTypes, projectFunctionalTagTypes, dispatchUpdateVariantNote, dispatchUpdateFamilyVariantTags, dispatchUpdateFamilyVariantFunctionalTags, isCompoundHet, variantId },
) => (
  family ?
    <NoBorderTable basic="very" compact="very" celled>
      <Table.Body>
...
```

I verified that `family` is set. I want to just select `NoBorderTable` in my `jest/enzyme` tests. Here is my tests code:

```
describe('Testing FamilyVariantTags clone tags functionality', () => {
    let wrapper
    beforeEach(() => {
      const store = configureStore()(STATE1)
      const stateProps = { 
        variant: VARIANT2,
        familyGuid: VARIANT2.familyGuids[0],
      }   
      const dispatchProps = { 
        cloneToIllumina: cloneToIlluminaMock,
      }   
      wrapper = shallow(<FamilyVariantTags store={store} {...stateProps} {...dispatchProps} />)
----> console.log(wrapper.debug())
  })  

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })  

  it('initializes dropdown tag correctly from the passed match parameters (url)', () => {
      const tagsElem = wrapper.find('NoBorderTable')
----> console.log(tagsElem.debug()) //PRINTS NOTHING!!!
  })
```

Printing out the `wrapper` using `console.log(wrapper.debug())` gives me the following:

```
<Memo() store={{...}} variant={{...}} familyGuid="F000069_sf8313488_wes_cidr" 
    cloneToIllumina={[Function: cloneToIllumina]} variantId="2-166773969-T-C" family={{...}} 
    projectTagTypes={{...}} projectFunctionalTagTypes={{...}} variantTagNotes={{...}} project=
    {{...}} combineVariants={false} dispatchUpdateVariantNote={[Function: 
    dispatchUpdateVariantNote]} dispatchUpdateFamilyVariantTags={[Function: 
    dispatchUpdateFamilyVariantTags]} dispatchUpdateFamilyVariantFunctionalTags={[Function: 
    dispatchUpdateFamilyVariantFunctionalTags]} storeSubscription={{...}}
 />
```

So, obviously there is no `NoBorderTable` or any other elements present except of this `Memo`. Versions of the packages I am using:

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"jest": "^24.9.0",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
```

How could I `find` elements with `shallow` `enzyme` rendering when there is `Memo`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with Memo, but with `shallow`. Shallow doesn't render child components nor execute lifecycle events. So for testing events and interactions, use `mount`. In most cases `mount` is used where as `shallow` is used for snapshot testing.